# How to use aggregation framework to search text with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As mentioned in the [Release Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-enhancements) of MongoDB 2.6, now we can do the text search in aggregation framework. So I can do something like this in the shell

```js
db.products.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $text: {
            $search: 'keyword'
        }
    }
}]);
```

Everything works alright here. Now I want to do the same thing with NodeJS with:

```
var aggrConditions = [{
    $match: {
        $text: {
            $search: 'keyword'
        }
    }
}];
db.collection(PRODUCT_COLL_NAME).aggregate(aggrConditions, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // do something
});
```

It complains about:

> exception: invalid operator: $search

I'm using node native client 1.4.5. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should work. Works for me. Make sure you are in your own project folder with the correct dependency in `package.json` and install locally and not globally. Also be sure you are actually connecting to a MongoDB 2.6 instance.

Comment: @NeilLunn God you are right, the target mongodb is not 2.6. I should have noticed it's such an obvious reason, which have spent me hours to figure out.